# "My Inbox": how to enable full width within Fiori launchpad?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm extending My Inbox standard Fiori app so that it fits the whole screen like the image bellow.

[image]

Hence, I've added in the `manifest.json` of my My Inbox extension (and the apps used in My Inbox, just in case) this line:

```json
{
  "sap.ui": {
    "fullWidth": true
  }
}
```

When the app is launched, it begins to be full screen, but then it comes back to the standard presentation.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Have you tried searching by "fullWidth" in the respective _My Inbox_ documentation? I could find e.g. [\[1\]](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e157c391253b4ecd93647bf232d18a83/Cloud/en-US/d4c4f2f1bfa447acb51cbc1fd577aa43.html?q=fullwidth) and [\[2\]](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0e602d466b99490187fcbb30d1dc897c/2105.500/en-US/865dddc8717e408f91209697497e4a55.html?q=fullwidth) that mention `fullWidth`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I've check your doc but it seems the mentions of `fullWidth` refer to what I put in my manifest.json :/

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a solution : the fullwidth is actually redefine in the `Component.js of` My Inbox standard app.
So I added these lines in the My Inbox extension project :

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "sap.ui": {
    "fullWidth": true
  }
}
```

`Component.js`

```
this.cross.fnd.fiori.inbox.Component.extend("cross.fnd.fiori.inbox.CA_FIORI_INBOX_EXTENSION.Component", {
    metadata: {
        manifest: "json"
    },
    
    /* Override code : begin ----------------------------------------------------- */
    //function to handle the width of the application. It is called by FLP when app is active.
    active: function () {
            sap.ushell.services.AppConfiguration.setApplicationFullWidth(true);
    }
    /* Override code : end ----------------------------------------------------- */
});
```